# Why values can not be replaced with their extensionally equal values in an intensional system?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Thomas Streicher states in [Investigations into Intensional Type Theory](https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/HabilStreicher.pdf)(§Introduction p.5) that:

> Although in Intensional constructive set theory (Intensional Type Theory) one can do most of the things one wants to do... certain theorems simply do not hold due to the lack of extensionality. A typical example is that from $t\in B a$ and $p\in Id A ab$ one is not allowed t conclude that $t\in Bb$ where $A$ is a type and $B$ is a family of types indexed over $A$.(But of course one is allowed to infer $t\in Bb$ from $t\in Ba$ and $a=b\in A$ !)

An almost similar thin is mentioned in [Definition of extensional and propositional equality in Martin-Lof extensional type theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/112555/definition-of-extensional-and-propositional-equality-in-martin-lof-extensional-t)
:

> The (Id-DefEq) means that extensional equality is baked into the type system: if you have a type constructor :((:)→)→ then you can use a value of type   in a context expecting   if  and  map equal inputs to equal outputs. Again this is not true in an intensional system, where   and  might be incompatible if they're syntactically different.

Why is that? Isn't it that two functions that are producing exactly same output for their inputs, equal? So why can't one be replaced with another in a context? What makes definitionally equal functions eligible to be replaced with each other, but not the extensionally equal ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensionally equal objects can be replaced by each other freely *in all extensional contexts*.  That is, if you say something about a function that depends only on its values, then if that statement is true about some function $f$ then it is also true about any other function $g$ that takes the same values as $f$ (i.e. is extensionally equal to it).

The point is that not all contexts are extensional.  In particular, in Streicher's example, the property "$t\in B a$" of a term $t$ is not extensional.  One might say that a term in type theory represents an "intension" or a "sense", which *has* an "extension" or "reference" but is not identical to it.

The situation of different algorithms for computing the same function is a good example, as Alexis mentioned.  Another manifestation in computation is that you might have two implementations of the same data structure, e.g. lists as implemented with arrays or pointers.  The two representations are extensionally identical, and hence can be substituted for each other in any "extensional" context (which in this case means any function that uses only the "interface" of lists); but some functions can also "peek beneath the hood" and use the representation, thereby no longer being extensional.

For a philosophical (though not uncontroversial) example, the Fregean notions of "sense" and "reference" may be helpful.  For instance, "the morning star" and "the evening star" are extensionally equal (both refer to the planet Venus), but there are contexts in which it doesn't make sense to replace one by the other: "the morning star is visible at dawn" wouldn't make sense as "the evening star is visible at dawn".

For an example in mathematics, recall that in dependent type theory, propositions are represented by particular types, and proofs by their inhabitants.  For instance, Fermat's Last Theorem is a type, as is $1+1=2$.  Since both of these are true, they have the same extension, namely the truth value "true".  But a proof of $1+1=2$ still doesn't count as a proof of FLT, i.e. $t \in (1+1=2)$ doesn't imply $t\in \rm FLT$.

Answer (score 0):

From a computational point of view, two functions that are equal extensionally can be very different intensionally. Sorting functions are a good example: two different [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) can produce the same ordered set from the same input, yet differ in terms of things like [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) and [time/space tradeoffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%E2%80%93space_tradeoff).